# How can I get an input date from a form in a controller in spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to do a form for an user and I have a input birthdate of type date:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" th:field="*{birthdate}">
```

My user entity has anything like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {
    ...

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private Date birthdate;
    ...
}
```

And in my controller I try to get the input this way:

```
@PostMapping("/admin/user/{userId}")
    public String submitModUser(Model model, @Valid User user)
```

But user.getBirthdate() is always null. Anybody knows why? I suspect that the form send it in string with my locale FR, and my controller can't transform it to java.util.Date.

Thanks

Comment: two thing 1) missing `@RequestBody` and 2) `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most modern browsers send dates in ISO format, so this should do the trick:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {
   ...

   @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
   private Date birthday;
   ...
}
```

Use your browsers developer tools (e.g. Chrome's Network Tab) to inspect the submitted form data.

Answer (score 0):

You have define Date format on birthdate in your User class

i.e.

```
  // Formats output date when this DTO is passed through JSON
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")

// Allows dd/MM/yyyy date to be passed into GET request in JSON
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Comment: I don't understand where to put this. In the controller? I tried in controller, but doesn't work anyway

Comment: You have to put this to your entity before "birthdate"

Comment: You're submitting form data here so @JsonFormat is not neccessary. Inspect the actual submitted form data to determine the date format. I would expect your browser to send data in ISO format...